# Floating point precision in python for a convergent sequence starts oscillating

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot a mathematical expression in python. I have a sum of functions `f_i` of the following type

`-x/r^2*exp(-rx)+2/r^3*(1-exp(-rx))-x/r^2*exp(-r x_i)`

where `x_i` values between 1/360 and 50. r is quite small, meaning `0.0001`. I'm interested in plotting the behavior of these functions (actually I'm interested in plotting `sum f_i(x) n_i`, for some real n_i) as `x` converges to zero. I know the exact analytical expression, which I can reproduce. However, the plot for very small `x` tends to start oscillating and doesn't seem to converge. I'm now wondering if this has to do with the floating-point precision in python. I'm considering very small `x`, like `0.0000001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.0000001 isn't very small.
Check out these pages:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info
Try casting your intermediate values in the computations to float before doing math.

Comment: thanks for your comment. my function declaration already takes it as floats. I was sceptical as I look at fractions of these types.

Comment: The actual limits of the floats values looks like it should be the IEEE double, if it goes to zero or large you only lose precision in one direction. Explicitly casting in the math ops could be good. If x is approaching zero then perhaps it could become NaN, you can test for that, print the equations and the results, see where it is breaking.